# referring methods in \ref command

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

how can I refer to a objective-c method in a \ref command in doxygen? I tried these but they don't work:

```
 @interface Class 
/// \ref Class::method
/// \ref Class::method:description
/// \ref Class#method
/// \ref Class#method:description
- (void) method:description;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **\sa** or **\see**.

\ref is used to reference pages, not referenced symbols.